# Azure Text to Speech API: New languages not available, yet?

Tags: c#, azure, rest, sdk, text-to-speech

I've been developing a TTS app using Azure Speech SDK and it was working OK until I found out that I get "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException" for certain languages.

To be specific, those are the neural voices with [新規作成] (newly added) flag listed at
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs.ja-jp/blob/master/articles/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/language-support.md.

I personally need to create TTS audio files now for km-KH-SreymomNeural and km-KH-PisethNeural and if anybody knows what I might be doing wrong, please kindly let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me i would consult this doc to see the supported languages and its always updated if there is other languages has been add:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support?tabs=stt-tts

i thank you a lot for verifying with me if that helped you or not :D

Answer (score 1):

Locale `km-KH` is supported by Azure Speech SDK. Could you try the latest version `1.23.0`?

Comment: Thank you for your information. I have been able to create voice files for km-KH using a sample program from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk. Sorry that my memory was vague and it turns out that I have created my app with Rest API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech?tabs=streaming). I'm not sure if I'm suppsed to ask you but it there any chance that RestAPI is yet to support km-KH or I might be doing something wrong (Again). I'm ready to re-create my app with SDK if necessary. Thank you.

Comment: REST API and SDK have the same voice coverage. But we recommend you to use SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I have followed your advice and been trying with SDK and is there any chance that SSML does not support some languaes like km-KH ?? My original app has been developed based on REST API with SSML feature and is this the reason why my app cannot create km-KH voice files at all? I have just tried to create km-KH voice files using SDK with SSML feature and the created files were emply while I was able to create en-US voice files without any problem. As I mentioned before, I was able to create km-KH voices without using SSML feature. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry again.. When I used a ssml created by https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/products/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/ for km-KH, I was able to create km-KH voice files so the SSML syntax I used in my app was not totally correct or up-to-date. Either way, many applogies for the fuss. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception?view=net-6.0) exception occurs when exceptions are thrown by the `HttpClient` and `HttpMessageHandler` classes.

> A base class for exceptions thrown by the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) and [HttpMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler?view=net-6.0) classes.

However, I could able to make this work using below code which converts text to speech using the key and region of your cognitive services and also saves the audio files in .wav format following [How to synthesize speech from text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-speech-synthesis?tabs=browserjs%2Cterminal&pivots=programming-language-csharp).

> ```
> Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech; using
> Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
>
> class Program {
>     async static Task Main(string[] args)
>     {
>        string Key = "<KEY>";
>        string Region = "<REGION>";
>         var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(Key, Region);
>
>         config.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "km-KH-SreymomNeural";
>         using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput("audio.wav");
>
>         Console.WriteLine("Enter the Sample Text to Speech string");
>         using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer(config))
>         {
>             string textToSpeech = Console.ReadLine();
>             await synth.SpeakTextAsync(textToSpeech);
>             var synth1 = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, audioConfig);
>             synth1.SpeakTextAsync(textToSpeech);
>         }
>
>         Console.WriteLine("Done Converting!");
>         
>         Console.ReadKey();
>     } }
> ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input. Sorry for my late reply. I have tried it myself and confirmed it works!